# Make a Debian Windows Subsystem for Linux share PATH

Tags: path, debian, environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently downloaded a Debian WSL, and I love it! However, all of the commands I used to be able to use(`git`, `rustc`, `rustdoc`, etc) don't work anymore. I'm guessing this is a problem with not sharing the regular environment variables and PATH? Should I do something to make Debian use my regular one? Thanks!

I really only want Debian for a Bash Shell with the packages, not as a complete separate environment.

Comment: Then why not you install those with `apt install`?

Comment: I could, but I guess I'd rather figure out how to use the same stuff I usually use

Comment: I installed the Windows versions so I could use them in Command Prompt

Comment: See this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/12/22/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/